# A physical device can be in three states: A, B, C. The device has an underlying Markov Chain and Markov Process to describe time jumps.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

> A physical device can be in three states: A, B, C. The device operates as follows (all time units are in hours):
>
> - The device spends an exponentially distributed amount of time in state A (with mean of 12 minutes) and then with probability 0.6 goes to state B, and with prob. 0.4 goes to state C.
> - When in state B, the device moves to state C after an Exp(3) amount of time.
> - When in state C, the device goes to state A at rate 1/hour, and to state B at rate 2/hour.
>     Let $X_t$ represent the device state at time $t$, and suppose $X_0 = A$.
>     Compute:
>
> (a) Probability the device is in state 'A' after 30 minutes.
>
> (b) Probability the device is in state 'A' after 30 minutes given that it was in state 'B' after 5 minutes and in state 'C' after 10 minutes.
>
> (c) The long-run proportion of time the device spends in state `A'.

So when approaching this problem it is easy for me to figure out the underlying markov chain and its corresponding p transition matrix. I am struggling with approaching how to find the jump rate matrix as well as how to approach part a. I think if I understood how to determine the time portion, the other parts should follow fairly naturally, but I don't get how to use the exponential distribution information given.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to understand how to convert between different descriptions of exponential distributions and Markov chains.

For exponential distributions, the following are equivalent:

- Sleep for an $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ time before waking up.
- Sleep for an exponentially distributed time with mean $\lambda^{-1}$ before waking up.
- Transition from sleep to waking up at a rate of $\lambda$.

For a Markov chain, there are two ways to view transitions: the "call center" model and the "direct line" model. The following are equivalent:

- Wait for $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ time for the phone to ring. Then get a call from Alice with probability $p_A$, from Bob with probability $p_B$, from Charlie with probability $p_C$, etc.
- Wait for $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda p_A)$ time for a phone call from Alice, or for $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda p_B)$ time for a phone call from Bob, or for $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda p_C)$ time for a phone call from Charlie, etc. (Whichever comes first.)

In other words, the possible transitions from a state can be thought of as having several competing exponential distributions going at once, and picking the smallest, or as having a single exponential distribution going, and picking which way to go once it's done.

The driving property behind this equivalence is that for exponential distributions, we have
$$
  \min\{\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_1), \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_2), \dots, \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_n)\} = \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \dots + \lambda_n).
$$

Comment: I guess what I am struggling with then is how do I know how to measure the probability that it is in state A. Like how do I quantify P(never leaves A) + P(Leaves and then goes to C then A) P(leaves, goes to C goes to B then A) +.....

Comment: Or in this case, if I let u(i,j) be the transition properties of the underlying markov chain, would p(i,j) = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{\lambda*t} \frac{(\lambda*t)^n}{n!} u^n (i,j)$
where \lambda = sum of the individual exponentials?